# Multiple tags on the same Go struct member

Tags: json, reflection, tags, go

I feel like this should be a minor problem, but I've tried every pattern that I can think of, and I haven't had any luck. I have a structure that needs to be encodable by both the `encoding/json` and [`github.com/zeebo/bencode`](https://github.com/zeebo/bencode) packages. It happens to include a channel, which cannot be encoded by either package. Thus, it needs to carry the tag `"-"`, so that that field is skipped.

```
type Index struct {
    Data data
    Queue chan string `json:"-"`
}
```

This is valid when encoded by the `json` package, but fails with the `bencode` package.

```
type Index struct {
    Data data
    Queue chan string `bencode:"-"`
}
```

This block, of course, has the complimentary problem. I have tried tag syntaxes like `json:"-",bencode:"-"`, `*:"-"`, `"-"`, `-`. Is there a solution?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Spaces appear to be the delimiter between struct tags when used for encoding hints.

Example:

```
type TaggedStructExample struct {
    ...
    J int `datastore:",noindex" json:"j"`
}
```

From: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Properties

In your case, try:

```
type Index struct {
    Data data
    Queue chan string `bencode:"-" json:"-"`
}
```

Comment: That was the one thing I didn't try! Thank you very much.

Comment: From http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag:

By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

Comment: In other words, the space is optional, but no other separator works.